# Getting raw fix messages via quickfix C++

Tags: quickfix

Is there a way to get a log of all messages in raw format that are sent via an initiator in quickfix? Specifically, I'm unable to log in after calling the initiator.start() method, and would like to know what fix logon message is getting sent as a result. I hope this will help me understand why my logon keeps failing.

Answer (score 1):

please take a look here:

http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html#Logging

In the Logging session you can specify a folder to log all messages.

Answer (score 1):

By default all messages are logged in the [FileLogPath](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html#Logging), but are broken down into header and body components, if my memory serves me right. But your problem seems to be logging in, so try printing out the FIX message in **toAdmin** and **fromAdmin** to your console or to a file if you want. In the reject message you should see the reason why your login was rejected(tag 58 if it exists). Try not using a DB, as DB transactions might slow down your engine, if you are logging loads of messages.